# how to write a surface only to get data on android?

Tags: android

I am using mediaProjection.CreateVirtualDisplay() and I can create MediaCodec and then create surface by the codec but I wonder if there is anyway to create surface only to get the virtual display data not to encode it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [Surface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface) from an [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader).

Once a frame is rendered onto the surface you can read it using the `acquireLatestImage()` method.

You can also set a listener to be invoked each time a new image becomes available with `setOnImageAvailableListener()`.

Comment: I do not want to get the image I just wonder can I get the byte datas that is not encoded。the original data?

Comment: `android.media.Image` consists of `Planes` that provide access to the pixel data via a `ByteBuffer`. In general, you need to call `image.getFormat()`, `plane.getRowStride()`, `plane.getPixelStride()` in order to know how to interpret the bytes in the buffer.

Comment: `setOnImageAvailableListener` only trigger 3 time at index=0,index=1 and index=2 but my screen is always change ,why?

Comment: An `ImageReader` holds a fixed-side queue of buffers. Once you are done using an acquired image you have to call `image.close()` to release it back to the queue. Otherwise the producer will not be able to supply more frames.

Comment: is it same to use ImageReader or use MediaCodec? Is MediaCodec using h.265?

Comment: It's not the same. `MediaCodec` is a component that either decodes or encodes the video (depending on how it was configured). The encoding method (H.264, VP8, etc.) is also configurable. `ImageReader` lets you consume the images (video frames) in the same format in which the producer put them.

Comment: which do you prefer to use? `MediaCodec` or `ImageReader`?

Comment: It depends on what your goal is. If you need to store or send the video then you probably want to compress it using the `MediaCodec`. On the other hand, if you need to play the video in the UI or apply some image processing to it, then you probably want to work with uncompressed images. In which case an `ImageReader` can be useful.

Comment: thank you for your answer. and how to compress it using `MediaCodec` ?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) has some code examples to get started. Also, you will need to use a [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer) to write the compressed video into a container format (MP4).